# Angular2 Router 3.0 beta 1 - (Router Instruction replacement)

Tags: angular

Hi I have implemented following with Angular 2 Beta 17 version.

I am using tree-route on my tree component as follows (Angular2 Beta 17.),

```
<tree-view>
<tree-node [icon-class]="cssClass" [text]="text"  
  [treeRoute]="['/Detail',{ID: 10001}]" >        
</tree-node>
</tree-view>
```

Tree-route Directive implementation as follows,

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Inject } from 'angular2/core';
import { Instruction, Router, Location } from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
    selector: '[treeRoute]',
    inputs: ['routeParams: treeRoute'],
    host: {
        '[attr.href]': 'visibleHref'
    }
})
export class TreeRoute implements OnInit {

    private _routeParams: any[];
    private _navigationInstruction: Instruction;

    public visibleHref: string = '';

    constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) private _element: ElementRef, @Inject(Router) private _router: Router, @Inject(Location) private _location: Location) {
        _router.subscribe(_ => this.updateLink());
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var elem = <HTMLElement>this._element.nativeElement;
        var span = <HTMLElement>elem.querySelector('li > div > div.tree-node-content > span.tree-node-title');

        if (span != undefined) {
            span.onclick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        }
    }

    set routeParams(changes: any[]) {
        this._routeParams = changes;
        this.updateLink();
    }

    updateLink() {
        this._navigationInstruction = this._router.generate(this._routeParams);
        var navigationHref = this._navigationInstruction.toLinkUrl();
        this.visibleHref = this._location.prepareExternalUrl(navigationHref);
    }

    onClick() {
        this._router.navigateByInstruction(this._navigationInstruction);
    }
}
```

Now, I thought to upgrade my angular2 version to latest Angular2 RC4. We also have new router which is @angular/router: 3.0.0-beta.1.

I have tried to refactored my method and replace instructions with UrlTree but till now no success.

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
    selector: '[treeRoute]',
    inputs: ['routeParams: treeRoute'],
    host: {
        '[attr.href]': 'visibleHref'
    }
})
export class TreeRouteDirective implements OnInit {

    private _routeParams: UrlTree;

    public visibleHref: string = '';

    constructor( @Inject(ElementRef) private _element: ElementRef, @Inject(Router) private _router: Router, @Inject(Location) private _location: Location) {        
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        var elem = <HTMLElement>this._element.nativeElement;
        var span = <HTMLElement>elem.querySelector('li > div > div.tree-node-content > span.tree-node-title');

        if (span != undefined) {
            span.onclick = this.onClick.bind(this);
        }
    }

    set routeParams(changes: UrlTree) {
        this._routeParams = changes;
        this.updateLink();
    }

    updateLink() {
        this.visibleHref = this._router.serializeUrl(this._routeParams); 
    }

    onClick() {
        this._router.navigateByUrl(this._routeParams);
    }
}
```

With this implementation, am getting error as follows,

[image]

Is there any other way to replace router instruction in new Router? Can any one help me, where am doing anything wrong?

**You help will be appreciable!**

Comment: How and where from is `set routeParams(changes: UrlTree) {` called and what `UrlTree` is it and why do you think you can pass an `UrlTree` to `this._router.navigateByUrl(...)`?

Comment: set routeParams(changes: UrlTree) { -- Is called directly when we use this directive because its input value. I am using UrlTree because router.navigateByUrl( | UrlTree) in definition shown. Did i understood that wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't know `navigateByUrl` also supports `UrlTree` in addition to `string`.

Comment: It seems the router has troubles with the passed `UrlTree`. How is the value created and where does it come from?

Comment: If you see in my question, am using Tree-route directive on Tree-node and passing my link similarly we pass on routerLink directive.  [treeRoute]="['/Detail',{ID: 10001}]". When we try to serializeUrl it throws the exception because in UrlTree it doesn't have a root.

Comment: I still have troubles understanding your code. I'd expect an `@Input() treeRoute:any[];` and `ngOnChanges()`. How do you get `['/Detail',{ID: 10001}]` into the new `TreeRouteDirective`?

Comment: Input attribute i have set inside directive definition itself. We are getting ['/Detail',{ID: 10001}] on set routeParams(changes: UrlTree) { .

Comment: Then I think you need to use `let urlTree = this._router.createUrlTree(this._routeParams)` and pass `urlTree` to `this._router.navigateByUrl(urlTree);` instead of `this._routeParams` directly.

Comment: What do you think then the type for _routeParams? right now, _routeParams are of type UrlTree.

Comment: I'd expect it to be `any[]` to match `['/Detail',{ID: 10001}]`